# Connect sharepoint custom list with Delphi

Tags: delphi, sharepoint

I created custom list in Sharepoint, I want to use it by database for my Delphi application but I didnt find out how to connect it with Delphi?

> i want to write, delete, read sharepoint list in delphi grid.but i
>   have a problem about connection.
>   **  what should i use for it, pls help, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access SharePoint objects from Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085475/access-sharepoint-objects-from-delphi)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SharePoint REST API to interface with SharePoint from any system/language that can make REST calls:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569.aspx